# Read SMS on expo

Tags: expo, react-native

How to read messages on Expo managed project?

i am working on react native project managed by expo. i want to read messages from the devices. how can i get access to messages?

i came across some packages but did not find any legit one. So is there a package  which can work on expo?

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "5.9.2",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.8.0",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^5.2.16",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.3",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.9.0",
    "axios": "^0.20.0",
    "expo": "~38.0.8",
    "expo-camera": "~8.3.1",
    "expo-file-system": "~9.0.1",
    "expo-font": "~8.2.1",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~8.2.1",
    "expo-sms": "~8.2.1",
    "expo-sqlite": "~8.2.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "^1.0.2",
    "firebase": "7.9.0",
    "formik": "^2.1.5",
    "react": "~16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.11.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-38.0.2.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.6.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.9.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "~3.0.7",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.9.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^2.15.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^7.0.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "yup": "^0.29.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.6",
    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.1.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have researched enough but there is not any support for reading messages in expo. We can send messages with expo-sms but we cant read and receive messages on expo.

So if you are using expo and want to use this native feature then you have to eject project from expo. And then you can use some library like react-native-get-sms-android to read and send SMS. i have used it in my project and works absolutely fine.

Comment: I have created a library to resolve this: https://github.com/maniac-tech/expo-read-sms

Some fine tuning is remaining, but this works for the core part

Comment: @AbhishekJain i hope if you can add option to read old messages too

Comment: @AhmedElsayed have not planned it as of now.....

Answer (score 2):

React Native doesn't provide any API to consume out of the box.

Expo also, doesn't expose any API.

I have created a library to use in Expo: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@maniac-tech/react-native-expo-read-sms

The purpose is to read the incoming SMS